# Merge dict header to request.headers.raw

Tags: python, starlette, httpx

`headers.raw` is `typing.List[typing.Tuple[bytes, bytes]]`

I want to merge it into another dict, like the one below:

```
client.build_request(headers=dict(request.headers.raw) | {"foo": "bar"}),
```

However I got the error

> expected "Union[Headers, Dict[str, str], Dict[bytes, bytes], Sequence[Tuple[str, str]], Sequence[Tuple[bytes, bytes]], None]"

Is there some way to do this? I am using Python 3.10, and I was planning to use the new features on merging dicts

Comment: Have you tried `client.build_request(headers=dict(request.headers.raw) | {b"foo": b"bar"})`?

Comment: No, I haven't tried. It works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `dict(request.headers.raw)` is of type `Dict[bytes, bytes]` and `{"foo": "bar"}` is of type `Dict[str, str]`. So when you do `dict(request.headers.raw) | {"foo": "bar"}` it's of type `Dict[bytes|str, bytes|str]` which won't match with the expected `headers` type hence the error.

So you could do this instead,

```
client.build_request(headers=dict(request.headers.raw) | {b"foo": b"bar"})
```